# Android Layout How to Set a Specific Fixed Layout Height

Tags: android

How can I set the height of a layout to be a specific number of dp.  Here is my exact situation:

I have a relative layout.  Inside I do an include of a header layout.  This header layout needs to be exactly 35dp.  How do I set an exact height.  Secondly I have a vertical separator image view inside the header that is a few 1 dp wide and that must be exactly 15dp high.  How do I set an image view inside the header to be an exact height?  I suppose I could do this indirectly by setting padding or margin?

Comment: can you post your layout xml code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
android:layout_height="35dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

By setting the height? :

```
<include
  ...
  android:layout_height="35dp"
```

Read more about includes [here](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html#Include) and the basic layout params [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_height)

Answer (score 0):

set layout_height parameter to 35dp